# Modifying Parent Value Through Input

Tags: angular, typescript

So I am trying to make a simple modal module and I want to be able to pass it a simple attribute to dictate whether it should be opened or not.

So the parent component passes it a boolean through an input value like so:

```
<modal [(show)]="showModal"></modal>
```

This works well enough, and the modal shows up as expected.  However, since the modal has it's own close button, it needs a way to pass the value change back through the input and set the value of `showModal` in the parent component back to `false`

I actually expected this would happen automatically, although I'm not sure why since there isn't anything actually passing back anything. So is there a way to modify the parent component value tied to the input without having to use `Output` and listen for it in the parent?

This is my current modal component:

```
export class ModalComponent {

    // Boolean to hold whether the modal is open or not
    modalOpen: Boolean = false;

    // Boolean used to toggle open class
    showModal: Boolean = false;

    // Boolean used to toggle display none/block
    hideModal: Boolean = true;

    // Function to open/close modal
    toggleModal = function(show: Boolean){
        if (show === true){
            this.hideModal = false;
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.showModal = true;
                this.modalOpen = true;
            }, 0)
        } else {
            this.showModal = false;
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.hideModal = true;
                this.modalOpen = false;
            }, 150)
        }
    }

    // Pulls in the "show" attribute and feeds it to toggleModal function
    @Input()
    set show( _show: Boolean ){
        if(typeof _show !== "undefined"){
            this.toggleModal(_show);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That won't work, the `@Input` and `@Output` decorators are one-directional bindings.

Comment: Is there anything that DOES work this way?

Comment: You could potentially use a shared service to manage the property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get this work I did need output, but I could actually tie it into the existing input.

The following output was added:

```
@Output() showChange = new EventEmitter();
```

And then where the value was being changed the following syntax let the input value be updated:

```
this.showChange.emit(true);
```

The resulting component looks like this:

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'modal',
    template: require('./modal.component.html'),
    styles: [ require("./modal.component.scss") ]
})

export class ModalComponent {

    // Boolean used to toggle open class
    showModal: Boolean = false;

    // Boolean used to toggle display none/block
    hideModal: Boolean = true;

    // Function to open/close modal
    toggleModal = function(show: Boolean){
        if (show === true){
            this.hideModal = false;
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.showModal = true;
                this.showChange.emit(true);
            }, 0)
        } else {
            this.showModal = false;
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.hideModal = true;
                this.showChange.emit(false);
            }, 150)
        }
    }

    // Pulls in the "show" attribute and feeds it to toggleModal function
    @Input()
    set show( _show: Boolean ){
        if(typeof _show !== "undefined"){
            this.toggleModal(_show);
        }
    }

    // Updates show boolean in the parent component
    @Output() showChange = new EventEmitter();
}
```